# how to get a particular line from a text file using a key word in node js

Tags: node.js

Iam trying to get a line in a file with a keyword and take that full line into a variable.
can anyone help me to find a line in a text file starting with a keyword.

Comment: please post a code that's not working instead of asking community to write one.

Answer (score 0):

Try the readline module: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_example_read_file_stream_line_by_line

Just check each line for the value you are looking for using a regexp.